# Unable to import a package

Tags: go

I'm having some trouble to import a package though I added a valid import path. I can make it works by using a alias but when I try a recompile, it fails again and complains again.

It first complains about an unused package and then about a undefined symbol. Here is the Travis-CI build : https://travis-ci.org/Blackrush/gofus/builds/12145834 the same is happening on my computer using go1.1.2 linux/amd64.

Why does it fail to compile and how can I fix this issue ?

Comment: It would help if you would extract the details of your problem and post them here. In addition to making it easier for us to help you, it also makes it easier for others with your problem. Furthermore, it preserves the information for others in the event that TravisCI invalidates your link sometime in the future.

Personally, I'm having a hard time understanding what your build is trying to do. If you could make it more clear by refining the information to the relevant details, I would be happy to try to help.

Answer (score 2):

The code in package `github.com/Blackrush/gofus/realm/network/frontend` has the package definition `network`, yet you are referencing it as `frontend.XXX` in `realm/config.go`.

This can be fixed by changing the references to `network.XXX` or by changing `package network` to `package frontend` in the frontend source code.

In general, it is best to give a package the same name as the directory in which its source is contained. So all code in directory `foo` should have a package declaration `package foo`. Otherwise you may run into confusing errors like this.

Comment: I think the compiler have to show a bit more information for such silly issues. I will have to review a bit more next time ...